# Generating scalatest methods in intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have an existing scala codebase. I am using intellij 13.1. I select a class file, press command-shift-T. I am prompted to create a test case. I create a new one, select scalatest, and select several methods. I click ok, select the target.

I wind up with the following - I am expecting methods for the methods I selected because junit would do this. Am I missing something obvious or is this just not supported?

```
package com.myApp.snippet

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

/**
 * Created by me on 8/08/2014.
 */
class ClassViewTest2 extends FunSuite {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this and make sure you have the needed libraries and plugins: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_intellij

Comment: Yes that was the instruction set I followed to get to where I am. Any other ideas?